# Javascript HREF updating

Tags: javascript, href

I have some URLs I visit occasionally that have page numbers indicated in the HREF.  These change and I need to keep track of the last one visited.  I have been doing this by cutting-pasting into a text file, but want to replace this with a local HTML page that I can update with javascript.  Here is an example I created:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
      function update(n,newvalue) {
           var link = document.getElementById('l' + n);
           var href = link.getAttribute('href', 2);
           var textfield = document.getElementById('p' + n);
           var parts = new Array();
           parts = href.split('-');
           parts[1] = 'p' + newvalue;
           textfield.setAttribute('value', newvalue);
           var newhref = parts.join('-');
           link.setAttribute('href',newhref);
       }
</script>
<form>
     <dl>
         <dt><a target="_blank" id="l1" href="http://foobar.org/t5-p8-data.html">Task 5 Data<a></dt>
         <dd>Page: <input type="text" id="p1" value="8" onChange="update(1,this.value)" /> </dd>
     </dl>
</form>
    </html>
```

When I enter a new value in the text field and trace through this with Firebug it seems to work fine, i.e. the link href value and the textfield value get changed in the DOM, but when the function exits they are back to the original values in the page.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me in Fx4 - I would personally use onKeyUp instead of onchange

Comment: I think the correct type is `text/javascript` - at least that's what's used basically everywhere.

Comment: Strange.  I try it in Fx 3.6.17 and IE 8 and it behaves as noted.  What could explain this?

Comment: (Unrelated: you're not closing the `<A>` in the `<DT>`)

Comment: @steve i was really interested in how you change the href value.  works like a charm, tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAJOR EDIT:

The problem is that a hitting enter in a single `<input>` inside a form tag will submit the form, so what happens is, you type in the input, hit enter, which causes a blor, so the `onchange` event fires and everything shows up fine in the debugger.  When that finishes, the page reloads (since the default form `action` is to GET the current page) without flicker, resetting the input value.

Solution 1: Remove the `<form>` tags.  The form element isn't doing anything useful in this snippet.

Solution 2: Add an `onsubmit=return(false)` attribute to the `<form>`.

Solution 3: Add another non-hidden input to the form.

Comment: Thanks, but same result.  Also changed script type to text/javascript.  I don't understand why it changes in the DOM during script execution but those changes don't stick when it exits.

Comment: Are you sure the page isn't reloading?  What is trigger the change, are you blurring the field by pushing enter, if so, the javascript is changing it then the enter keypress in a `<form>` with a single input is causing the form to submit reloading the page, since the default `action` of the form is the same page.

Comment: Yes it does seem to be reloading the page.  So I changed the script to include a button with onClick triggering the function instead of onChange in the input field.  The same thing happens, but maybe the button click triggers a reload too.  If so, question is what event could I use to trigger the script.  It can't be onKeyUp as @mplungjan suggested, because I might have to enter two numbers to update the page number.

Comment: Aha...key seems to be to remove the form tags, then no reload.

Comment: @Steve, `<button>` has a `type` attribute which is `submit` by default.  Try `<button type=button>` to avoid any form submission.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp